# MethodError while performing MCMC using Turing.jl in Julia

Tags: julia, ode, bayesian, mcmc

I'm trying to use the Bayesian ODE example [here](https://turinglang.org/v0.25/tutorials/10-bayesian-differential-equations/) from Turin.jl package to make an inference to the following system:

```
function ice(du, u, p, t)
    εₘ, εₖ, σ, F, d, ε = u
    Aₘ, Qₘ, n, pₘ, R, T, Eₖ, Eₘ, η, dₛₛ, Fₛₛ, ε₁, ε₂, S  = p
    
    du[1] = Aₘ * (σ/F)^n * d^(-pₘ) * ℯ^(-Qₘ/(R*T))
    du[2] = (σ - Eₖ*εₖ)/η
    du[3] = Eₘ*(S - ((σ - Eₖ*εₖ)/η) - (Aₘ * (σ/F)^n * d^(-pₘ) * ℯ^(-Qₘ/(R*T))))
    du[4] = S*(Fₛₛ - F)/ε₁
    du[5] = S*(dₛₛ - d)/ε₂
    du[6] = S
end
```

However, when I run the chain I get the following error:

```
MethodError: ^(::Irrational{:ℯ}, ::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.TuringTag, Float64}, Float64, 12}) is ambiguous.
```

Here are the steps I use for a working example:

parameters, initial conditions, and timespan:

```
p = [0.7, 70.0, 3.5, 0.35, 8.315, 265.0, 4.0e9, 9.0e9, 1.0e11, 0.00025, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0e-6];
u_0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.001, 0.0];
tspan = (0,1000);
prob = ODEProblem(ice, u_0, tspan , p)
```

Generating some noisy data from the solution:

```
sol = solve(prob, Rosenbrock23(); saveat=0.15);
p1 = Array(sol[3,:]) + 0.8 * randn(size(Array(sol[3,:])));
p2 = Array(sol[6,:]) + 0.8 * randn(size(Array(sol[6,:])));
odedata = [reduce(hcat, p1); reduce(hcat, p2)];
```

My model and prior assumptions are:

```
@model function fit_ice(data::AbstractMatrix, prob)
    # Prior distributions
    σₑᵣ ~ InverseGamma(2, 3)
    Aₘ ~ Uniform(0.0,10)
    Qₘ ~ Uniform(10,1e4)
    n ~ Uniform(0.5,5.0)
    pₘ ~ Uniform(0.0,1.0)
    Eₖ ~ Uniform(1e9,9e9)
    Eₘ ~ Uniform(1e9,9e9)
    η ~ Uniform(1e9,1e12)
    dₛₛ ~ Uniform(1e-5,1e-3)
    Fₛₛ ~ Uniform(0.0,1.0)
    ε₁ ~ Uniform(0.01,1.0)
    ε₂ ~ Uniform(0.01,1.0)
    S = 1e-4
    R = 8.3145
    T = 263

    # Simulate the model but save only σ and ε
    p = [Aₘ, Qₘ, n, pₘ, R, T, Eₖ, Eₘ, η, dₛₛ, Fₛₛ, ε₁, ε₂, S]
    predicted = solve(prob, Rosenbrock23(); p=p, saveat=0.15, save_idxs=[3,6])

    # Observations
     for i in 1:length(predicted)
        data[:, i] ~ MvNormal(predicted[i], σₑᵣ^2 * I)
    end

    return nothing
end
```

```
model2 = fit_ice(odedata, prob)
```

and after trying to execute the following:

```
chain2 = sample(model2, NUTS(0.45), MCMCSerial(), 50, 2; progress=true)
```

I get the error.

It seems like there is a problem with the exponential term in the ODE system, but I'm not sure how to fix that, since the numerical integrator has no issues solving it.

Comment: after the `...  is ambiguous.` line of the error message, there should be lines about what methods the ambiguity is between. could you post the rest of the error message too?

Comment: I'm unsure where the ambiguity comes from, but try `exp(...)` instead.